# Нужна ли запятая перед "когда" в обоих случаях?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

1. Мы приедем(,) когда захотим.
2. Мы приедем тогда(,) когда захотим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В первом случае возможны оба варианта.**
Розенталь:

> Выражения с глаголом *хотеть*, образующие цельные по смыслу выражения,
> запятой не разделяются: *пиши как хочешь* (‘пиши по-всякому’); *над ним
> командует кто хочет; его не гоняет только кто не хочет; приходи когда
> хочешь; бери сколько хочешь; гуляй с кем хочешь; делай что хочешь;
> распоряжайтесь как хотите; напишет какую хочешь статью; выпьет какое
> хочешь вино; женись на ком хочешь.*
>
> Но: *женился, на ком хотел*; *женится, на ком захочет* — при расчлененном
> значении глаголов, образующих сказуемое неполного предложения.

**Во втором случае запятая обязательна.**

Answer (score 2):

*Мы приедем, **когда захотим**. Мы приедем тогда, **когда захотим**.*

1. Я бы поставила запятую в обоих случаях: Мы приЕдем, когда захотИм. Это СПП с придаточным времени, но не устойчивое выражение. Расстановка ударений, наличие пауз —  всё говорит об этом.

Здесь дело **не в семантике глагола "хочешь"**, а в том, что на его основе легко образуются **устойчивые сочетания** с подчинительными союзами: как хочешь, что хочешь и т.д.

Также многое зависит **от структуры предложения** (простое, сложное, осложненное однородными членами). Расстановка ударений должна быть такой, чтобы ударение падало на оборот. И чем короче оборот, тем более это вероятно.

2. Можно **сравнить примеры из Нацкорпуса**.

(1) Его можно было спросить что захОчешь ― ни разу не было, чтобы не знал. Будешь достойным человеком, всё тебе будет ― и магнитофОн, и все что захОчешь.

(2) Напиши кАк хочешь и чтО хочешь. Можно делать что хОчешь. Это люди что хоОчешь // сделают с тобой.

Вариант (2) встречается чаще, чем вариант (1), так как легче вписывается в предложение.

3. **Для сравнения**: *Мы приедем **когда захотИм**, вас спрашивать не будем.*

В предложении другой структуры оборот не обособляется (здесь это устойчивое выражение).